# MySQL Select Where max date and max time

Tags: mysql, select, max

I have this kind of table:

```
CREATE TABLE Buckets (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    checkDate DATE NOT NULL,
    checkTime TIME NOT NULL,
    accountId CHAR(13),
    costCenter VARCHAR(30),
    percentage DECIMAL(5,2),

    UNIQUE INDEX (checkDate, checkTime, accountId, costCenter),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There I have currently this kind of data:

```
1 2014-03-24 08:11:27 387909559196 72350 86.92
2 2014-03-24 08:11:27 387909559196 analytics 12.71
3 2014-03-24 08:11:27 387909559196 json-files 0.36
4 2014-03-24 08:11:27 387909559196 cloud 0.01
5 2014-03-25 08:11:27 387909559196 72350 86.92
6 2014-03-25 08:11:27 387909559196 analytics 12.71
7 2014-03-25 08:11:27 387909559196 json-files 0.36
8 2014-03-25 08:11:27 387909559196 cloud 0.01
9 2014-03-25 08:38:55 387909559196 72350 86.92
10 2014-03-25 08:38:55 387909559196 analytics 12.71
11 2014-03-25 08:38:55 387909559196 json-files 0.36
12 2014-03-25 08:38:55 387909559196 cloud 0.01
```

I would like to make Select which selects max date and then max time. In this case results should include only rows 9-12.

So far I have tried this kind of query, but unfortunately I'm not getting the results what I want:

```
SELECT b.id, b.checkDate, b.checkTime, b.AccountId, b.costCenter, b.percentage, c.id, c.name FROM Buckets b
JOIN CustomerAccounts ca ON (b.accountId= ca.linkedAccountId)
JOIN Customer c ON (ca.customerId = c.id)
WHERE checkDate = (SELECT max(checkDate) FROM Buckets)
AND checkTime = (SELECT max(checkTime) FROM Buckets)
```

Comment: Provide  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with proper definitions of your schema and also add your desired result set you want from query

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do here. Please clarify. Also include table description for the other 2 tables you are using in your join.

Comment: Hey, sorry for this kind of question but luckly Vignesh Kumar managed to solve my problem! And also co-worker managed to give me another solution also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT b.id, b.checkDate, b.checkTime, b.AccountId, b.costCenter, b.percentage, c.id, c.name     
  FROM Buckets b JOIN CustomerAccounts ca ON (b.accountId= ca.linkedAccountId)
                 JOIN Customer c ON (ca.customerId = c.id)
) AS S JOIN 
(
  SELECT max(checkDate) AS MaxDate,max(checkTime) As MaxTime FROM Buckets
) AS T ON T.MaxDate = S.checkDate AND S.checkTime = T.MaxTime
```

Comment: On this solution there were couple typos, but managed to figure them out by deleting b.id from first select and on the "AS T ON T.MexDate" there is typo.