# Select max date and max time from query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my current data in database.

```
    ========================================
    id | IC      |date         |time       |
    1  | test    |2017-07-27   |14:19:26   |
    2  | test    |2017-07-27   |14:20:26   |
    3  | second  |2017-07-28   |06:58:55   |
    ========================================
```

I want to get the maxdate and maxtime for each IC.

I tried:

```
SELECT id,pass_no,time_in,ic,date_in FROM `check_in` 
WHERE date_in = (SELECT MAX(date_in) FROM check_in) 
AND 
time_in = (SELECT MAX(time_in) FROM check_in) GROUP BY IC
```

But it only return the last row data for me. The result I wanted is like

```
    ========================================
    id | IC      |date         |time       |
    2  | test    |2017-07-27   |14:20:26   |
    3  | second  |2017-07-28   |06:58:55   |
    ========================================
```

Comment: See this link already asked by some one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629307/mysql-select-where-max-date-and-max-time

Comment: Store dates and times as single entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tuple and group by ic

```
  SELECT id,pass_no,time_in,ic,date_in 
  FROM `check_in` 
  WHERE (date_in, time_in, ic) in  (
        SELECT MAX(date_in), max(time_id), ic 
          FROM check_in
          GROUP BY id)
```

Comment: nice your answer works!

Answer (score 2):

This will return the max date & time per ic:

```
select ic, max(date), max(time)
from check_in
group by ic
```

Comment: but this return id 1 and 3 i tried, i want id 2 and 3

Comment: @ron Why didn't you described it correctly in your question? It just tells: "I want to get the maxdate and maxtime for each IC." Nothing about id.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 select max(time),date,id 
 from (select max(date) as date,time,id from check-in group by time,id ) 
 group by date,id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "OR" condition insteads "AND"?